# Prevent UIStepper from being 0?

Tags: ios, swift, uistepper

I have a `UIStepper` that has a `stepValue` of `1`. I would like the `UIStepper` to be able to be positive or negative up until its `maximum` and `minimum` values, but never `0`.

Every attempt I have made at solving this is unable to account for whether the stepper was decreasing or increasing (thus should skip `0` to `1` or to `-1`). The only other thing I can think of is saving the previous value and comparing, but that sounds a little involved for such a simple task.

Any ideas? Has anyone else ran into the same requirements?

Comment: what were your attempts?

Comment: On valueChanged, detect if 0, and hardcode either 1 or -1. But as I explained, I could not figure out a way to determine when to do which.

Comment: As the value is zero, whether the step was positive or negative is indeterminable without more information. You don't know what the state of the stepper was previously unless you keep a note of it. So it isn't as simple as it appears :)

Comment: @JonJ I keep a note of it... but by setting a variable to the value of the stepper in valueChanged calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this from a different direction.  Let the stepper do what it does, and just change your interpretation of it.

For example, if you have a stepper that you want to go from `-5` to `+5` but skipping `0`:

1. Set stepper `minumum` to `-5`.
2. Set stepper `maximum` to `4`.
3. Set stepper `stepValue` to `1`.
4. When you read the stepper `value`, add `1` if `value` is non-negative:

   ```
   let value = stepper.value + (stepper.value < 0 ? 0 : 1)
   ```
5. When you set the stepper `value`, first lower the positive values by `1`:

   ```
   // value of 3 will be represented in the stepper by 2
   value = 3
   stepper.value = value - (value > 0 ? 1 : 0)
   ```

---

**Hide the details with a `nonZeroValue` computed property**

You can hide these `+1` and `-1` adjustments by creating an extension to `UIStepper` that adds a new computed property called `nonZeroValue`.

```
extension UIStepper {
    var nonZeroValue: Double {
        get {
            return self.value + (self.value < 0 ? 0 : 1)
        }
        set {
            self.value = newValue - (newValue < 0 ? 0 : 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, just use `stepper.nonZeroValue` in place of `stepper.value` in your code.

Comment: Wouldn't this change when the stepper increment/decrement buttons grey out, if at all? (Have not tried yet.) I read the value in valueChanged and display in a label.

Comment: Try it.  It will do what you want.  Think of the stepper value as an internal implementation detail that needs to be mapped to what you are stepping over.  By lowering the maximum by 1, you now have a stepper than can step over the right number of values, you then just need to interpret the non-negative ones as one higher than the internal stepper value.

Comment: When you read the value in valueChanged, just do that calculation I show in step 4 before displaying in the label.

Comment: The stepper does not decrement, and it adds +2 every time.

Comment: `var quantity = sender.value; if quantity >= 0 { quantity += 1 }`

Comment: That is what I tried also. Still adds +2 on increment and only decrements if I tap and hold.

Comment: You must still have code that mucks with the value when it is changed (perhaps from the other answer).  The stepper should be free to change its values normally.

Comment: Nope. The method that is being called is literally your code and then updating the label.

Comment: Unless... what should the stepper value be set to in cellForRow? Currently it is set to contracts (or the global var for quantity).

Comment: Where the default value is 1, max is 100 (set to 99) and min is -100.

Comment: If you `set` the stepper value, you need to do the reverse mapping.  Subtract 1 before setting the value if > 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy with Key-Value Observation. It requires an `IBOutlet` of the stepper

```
@IBOutlet var stepper: UIStepper!
```

Declare an `NSKeyValueObservation` property

```
var observation : NSKeyValueObservation?
```

In `viewDidLoad` observe the `value` of the stepper and adjust it if the *new* value is 0. The benefit of KVO is that you get the `old` and `new` value to detect the step direction

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    observation = stepper.observe(\.value, options: [.old, .new], changeHandler: { (stepper, change) in
        if change.newValue! == 0.0 {
            if change.newValue! > change.oldValue! {
                stepper.value = 1
            } else {
                stepper.value = -1
            }
        } 
    })
}
```

If the stepper is in a table view cell declare the outlet and the `observation` property in the cell and assign the observer in `cellForRow` of the controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyGreatCell
    let model = datasource[indexPath.row] // just an example
    cell.stepper.value = model.stepperValue
    ... 
    cell.observation = cell.observe(\.stepper.value, options: [.old, .new], changeHandler: { (stepper, change) in
        if change.newValue! == 0.0 {
            if change.newValue! > change.oldValue! {
                stepper.value = 1
            } else {
                stepper.value = -1
            }
        }
        model.stepperValue = stepper.value
    } 
    return cell
 }
```

And you have to implement `didEndDisplaying` to deallocate the observer

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let tableCell = cell as! MyGreatCell
    tableCell.observation = nil
}
```

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to be working for me. If it helps, the UIStepper is in a table view cell. I also tried the code in viewDidAppear just in case the cell had to be laid out before it could work. Also, will this return the adjusted value to valueChanged call?

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to set the current value of the stepper and update the model in the `observation` closure in `cellForRow`. An `IBAction` for `valueChanged` is not needed.

Comment: Do I need to subclass my cell (not currently)? Is there a way to do this without subclassing the cell and preventing memory leaks? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to subclass the cell. Custom table view cells don't cause memory leaks by default unless you wrote ugly code.